# Bokeh Legend Object - passing assigned color to legend

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, colors, bokeh

I'm trying to create a fairly complex bokeh circle plot that features several complex interactions (axis changes & year slider & others). I've seemed to gotten it working mostly, and without the use of ColumnDataSource (because the template I borrowed didn't use it). Now I need to create a custom legend (or HoverTool(??)).

I've managed to create a custom legend, but I do not know how to pass the matplotlib color it was assigned into the legend. So currently, it is just a legend showing all the legend items but no color identifiers. How can I pass the right colors into the legend?

Here is the relevant chunk of my code:

dataframe:

```
FULLNAME | ES | TX | YEAR
Jim        3    12   2008
...
Tim        33    8   2009


import matplotlib
import random
from datetime import date

user_list= list(set((df["FULLNAME"])))

colordict=dict(matplotlib.colors.cnames.items())
colordict=list(colordict.values())
random_colors=random.sample(colordict,len(user_list))

def yr_slider():
    current=slider.value
    ys=df[y.value][df["YEAR"]==current].values
    p = figure(plot_width=930, plot_height=325, background_fill_color='snow', x_range=(2016,2019))
    p.circle(x=df["YEAR"][df["YEAR"]==current], y=ys, size= 20,
             color=random_colors)
    legend=Legend(items=[("Jim",random_colors[1]),
                         ("Tim",[])
                         ]) ###THIS AINT WORKIN RIGHT###
    p.add_layout(legend,'right')
    print(ys)
    return p

def update(attr, old, new):
    layout2.children[1]=yr_slider()
slider=Slider(start=2017, end=date.today().year, step=1, value=date.today().year, title="Year")
slider.on_change('value', update)

y=Select(title='X-Axis', value='ES',options=['TX','ES'])
y.on_change('value',update)

ctrls=widgetbox([y,slider], width=200)
layout2=row(ctrls,yr_slider())

curdoc().add_root(layout2)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legend items associate a label with a list of renderers, not with colors.

```
legend = Legend(items=[(label,list_of_GlyphRenderers)])
```

When you have several Glyphrenderers in the list, if they are of the same type, only the color of the first one will show.

If the first one uses multiple color, only the first color will show.

If the Glyphrenderers are of different types (e.g. circle and line), then they will be combined in the little icon of the legend.

The fact that you can have many renderers attached to a same legend item is mostly useful for this and for controlling the visibility of several renderers at the same time when enabling the interactive legend.

Here you have only one renderer `circle()`, but with different colors, so only the first color will be used. I don't know of a way to customize the legend icons directly.

You can have a separate call to Circle for each point

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import Legend
from bokeh.plotting import figure

names = ["Jim","Bob","Assia"]
colors = ["red","blue","green"]

fig = figure()
items = []
for i in range(3):
    items += [(names[i],[fig.circle(i,i,color=colors[i],size=20)])]
fig.add_layout(Legend(items=items),'right')
show(fig)
```

But using a Hovertool is probably better if you have many points.